# Quickest way to load data in JavaScript array from external source (mongo/csv etc)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, database

I have bunch of zip codes records (50k) with corresponding states they belong to in csv file (0.5 MB in size). I want to read it in array and later write my own function to see if user provided zip code matches with state.
Currently, I have those records in MongoDb and I do Async reading in the beginning of the application and it takes time. I do not ever need to update the data. Just one time read and array's filter function would do the required job for me.
Would you have any suggestion on alternative way of storing the data that is quicker to load?
Thank you,

Comment: The quickest way is to not load the data at all. If you have any data telling you about how often some zip codes will be used vs others, use that to load the frequently used zip codes first. Then (or instead, if you lack the data) divide the remainder into separate files based on the first, say, three digits, and load the appropriate file only after the user has typed enough digits.

Comment: Quite a valuable suggestion but no none of those requirements match to follow your idea. There are no indicators to minimize search criterion. If you have other idea for my situation that would be better. Do you think fetching data from Mongo is time consuming considering it provides other features that I do not need. Loading some csv or xml file for one time read is better?

Comment: You can always load data based on what the user has typed in. If the user types "0", load data from a file with all of the zip codes that start with "0". Or do a query against a Mongo or other database, limiting the search to what the user has typed. The format is unlikely to be the limiting factor; JSON, XML, CSV, you'll need to load and parse them all. I would think that JSON and XML might have an edge, since browsers have native parsers for those, but CSV is pretty darn trivial. As with all performance problems, testing is key; measure the time it takes, alter your code, measure again.

Comment: Its actually a program that takes in data and check zip codes stores in their matches with appropriate state. So it is not based if what user is typing. Thanks for your input. If you or anyone has any suggestions, I welcome that.